# Date in Firebase displays as yyyy-mm-dd format whereas form date is dd-mm-yyyy

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem my data that I submit in the Firebase Database is submitted  as `yyyy-mm-dd`  which is the date whereas the date in the form is `dd-mm-yyyy`.

I used slice in order to get the necessary 000z which worked but when I want to display the date it will not display because of the stored date in Firebase which is in the `yyyy-mm-dd` format.

Does anybody know how change the format submitted to firebase or any other way to get the date in the form like it was set?

Comment: In your JavaScript you should keep all dates as either ISO8601 format or as date structures using the Date object or a moment using Momentjs. Submitting to the server should occur using ISO8601. The **presentation layer** can then show the date in whatever format you want using the various built in date filter settings in Angular. In the database it should **always** persisted as a DateTime type.

Comment: dateofbirth: user.date.toJSON().slice(0, 10).toString(),      this what i use to push the date dateofbirth: 
"2016-02-12"
 this is what is the output in the db  i had a look at moment.js but  what is the best way to do it so I can  return the date in case it needs to be edited

Comment: don't use `slice` or `toString` on date values.  if you are using a JavaScript `Date` object, the date is stored as the number of milliseconds since midnight Jan 1 1970.  This can then be formatted however you like.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your  HTML template binding, see if it works.

```
{{date_expression (e.g 1288323623006) | date:'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss Z'}}
```